# Breakpoint all references to an external function?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a function in an external library, for which I do not have the source code, which is causing problems.

If I were putting in a breakpoint in my own code, I would put it on the first line of the function, but as it is an external function, I do not have that option.

Is there any way to as Visual Studio to break any time the function is called? My current workaround is to do a "Find All References" and put an individual breakpoint on every single call to the function, which is a sucky way of doing things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click Debug, New Breakpoint, Break at Function (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd>), then type the full name of the function.  (eg, `Namespace.ClassName.FunctionName`)

You can see the breakpoint in the Breakpoints window (Debug, Windows, Breakpoints, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>).
Make sure that the Hit Count column says *(Currently 0)*; if it doesn't, you got the name wrong.

Comment: Guh. I had seen this advice for C# questions, and wasn't seeing the option in the Debug menu. I guessed that Visual Basic's setup was different. Turns out that it disappears when you've got the designer window open. >_<

Comment: make sure "Just My Code" is disabled as well